# How to use yarn to create a React app project?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I am trying to create a new React project using *yarn* command on Windows.
I have tried the commands
`yarn init` and `yarn add react react-dom`. But it is only adding a few of the node modules to the project I created. And package.json contains only this many dependencies

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2"
  }
}
```

How can I add all the other dependencies and node modules before starting the project?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would recommend "create-react-app", simply "CRA".
"CRA" handles the most of the build configurations and they are hidden by default so you can focus on code. ( In some specific cases, you can eject and customize it by running commands "eject")

You can create the project using below command

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

To start the project simply run below commands

```
yarn start
```

To build projects

```
yarn build
```

You can eject the project with below command

```
yarn eject
```

Please reference this link for more details.
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Answer (score 8):

Before you start the project by using the following command:

```
yarn start
```

You need to install the modules by using:

```
yarn install // or simply, yarn
```

The following command will only install react, react-dom but not core dependency modules.

```
yarn add react react-dom
```

PS: I hope it should be `react-router-dom` instead of `react-dom`.

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 1):

### How to Create a React App Using Yarn?

To create a React app, use the `yarn create` command:

```
$ yarn create react-app <app_name>
```

This will automatically install the **create-react-app** script as a global **yarn** package on your machine. To verify if correctly install:

```
$ yarn global list
yarn global v1.22.17
info "create-react-app@4.0.3" has binaries:
  - create-react-app
```

If you've installed the **create-react-app** script with **npm**, you can remove it, and keep only the one installed with yarn:

```
$ npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

**ERROR**: However, you may get the following error when trying to start the app on macOS:

```
$ yarn start
my-app@0.1.0 start
react-scripts start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488
throw e;
^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/zzz/Develop/my-app/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/package.json
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:416:9)
at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:669:3)
at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (/Users/zzz/Develop/my-app/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/lib/safe-parser.js:1:17) {
code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
```

**FIX**: This bug probably would be resolved soon. For now, simply run a package upgrade then start the app again:

```
$ yarn upgrade
```

For more information read: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11579